# Executing a linux command through gradle returns exit status 127

Tags: gradle

I have this gradle task that runs the following on a machine using remote ssh connection:

```
 println execute(['nohup /opt/ESSyncBatch/runessync.sh &>/dev/null &'])
```

And here's the content of runessync.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $(dirname $0)
echo $(pwd)
java -Dspring.batch.job.names=CADB0200 -jar cics-batch.jar
```

If i run the nohup command on my own ssh connection manually (im using putty), it does the expected but when I run the task on gradle, it fails with the following error:

> > Command returned exit status 127: 'nohup /opt/ESSyncBatch/runessync.sh &>/dev/
> >     null &'

Any insights?

Comment: Found a workaround. I created another sh file that contains the following command: nohup /opt/ESSyncBatch/runessync.sh &>/dev/null & AND call this sh file on my gradle script instead.

Comment: You should configure the command being run this way: `['nohup', '/opt/ESSyncBatch/runessync.sh', '&>/dev/null', '&']`